# Triggering VBA `Worksheet_change()` for functions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Sub Worksheet_Change()` trigger on my workbook which maps any manual changes to certain cells of summary rows to another worksheet.

However, I've updated these summary cells to now use `=sum()` functions instead of requiring the users to manual change the values of the cells. As a result, my `Sub Worksheet_Change()` trigger now never fires as these summary cells are never actually changed.

Is there a way to trigger this update if one of the cells of interest has the result of it's formula updated?

Comment: two choices 1) change the fire capture to reflect cells that feed the formulas, or 2) use `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: Thank you - I had to go with 1) as I needed the target cell that was being changed